# Voice recording for radio, what effects are used?

Tags: audio-recording, effects

I'm recording my voice for my radio show. I used to record at the radio studio but we have a problem and so i'm stuck at home with Sound Forge.
I record the voice with a Cobalt C04 Mic that sounds ok to me, then i use "Normalize" and then "Wave Hammer".
What are the effects that are most commonly used on voice?

Answer (score 3):

Radio output in general will be compressed to within a millimeter of its life.  With multi-band compression in particular you can boost the loudness a hell of a lot and everything will sound very full.

But, as with everything, it depends:

- What you want it to sound like
- What the actual requirements are (anyone need anything specific?)
- What the source material is like

In terms of other 'effects', specifically effects, a small touch of reverb is fairly common in general although not so much on VOs.

Processing-wise, though:

- Noise gate, to cut background noise in a very simple way
- Compression (including multi-band) to boost signal strength/volume
- EQ to adjust tonality slightly, remove noise or add presence, remove sibilance etc..

But as I said, depends completely on the 3 points at the top.

Comment: That was then this is now.  Standards stop too much compression andor gain so as to normalize LOUDNESS.   See LUFS standard and related.